# Get details about digital signature

Tags: java, android, xml, crash

I would like to have details about the digital signature and on the Internet I found this code that prints the values ​​of the signature using the Log. I would like to use a TextView so I wrote this code.

Comment: TextView firma needs to be declared at the class level, scope issue. You can't append something to nothing.

Comment: I did it but it crashes the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: Was a little too quick there. The variable c also needs to be at class level scope, that's it.

Comment: Done but crash again :-( Always NullPointerException in firma.append

Comment: Then i would check the returned value of getSubjectDN().

Comment: If i use Log.d instead of firma.append, getSubjectDN return the name of the name of those who have signed. For example: John Rossi.